# Use Regex to remove RTF formatting in Android

Tags: java, android, regex, rtf

I am trying to obtain the plain text from a string containing `RTF` formatting.
For example, I have:

```
originalText = {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 the temp is forty degrees\par}
```

and I want to obtain:

```
plainText = the temp is forty degrees
```

I found the following *Regex* online: `({\)(.+?)(})|(\)(.+?)()`

So I tried this but it just gave me back the original expression:

```
        pattern = "({\\)(.+?)(})|(\\)(.+?)(\b)";
        plainText = originalText.replace(pattern,"123");
```